# speeding up gallery page

Tags: html, css, image

I have a HTML page with a jQuery gallery plugin. The gallery takes 15 images as well as 15 thumbnails. The page loads a little slow now, and I would like to increase the page load speed. I have a few fundamental questions:

1. If a `display:none` is specified on an image, I know it does not take up space in the document flow but is it still downloaded?

   If it is not, I can just download the first image and let the others pre-load once the rest of the page is done loading.
2. If the same image is specified twice on a page, is it downloaded once or twice?

   Instead of loading 15 images and then 15 thumbnails, I thought I would use the larger images as thumbnails also, specifying the `height` and `width` properties to make them small.

   For example,

   `<div id="main-image"><img src='something' alt='something' /></div>`

   `<div id="thumb-image"><img src='something' alt='something-else' width='50px'  height='50px' />`

Any other pointers to speed up the process would be very helpful. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: compress images , reduce dom element, use firebug to see what is taking more time and try to reduce

Comment: You can also use AJAX to post load all the other images...

Comment: hmm i will look into both comments but can you also please answer my 2 questions? Thanks.

Comment: The way to find out by yourself is to look in the "network" tab of the browser's developer tools while the page loads.

Comment: can you please describe by image how's your slider is looking because i want to know where is thumbnail images usage

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, they are still downloaded (common preload-trick, actually)
2. Repeated images are only downloaded once.

Where are you getting the jQuery plugin from?
Loading jQuery from google API will allow the browser to cache the script via google, which gives you and your users a slight increase in speed.

Answer (score 1):

Are the images on your home page? if not then you could pre-load the images first.

See a demo here http://www.thewindowdr.info then click gallery on nav bar.

create image-preload.js file and paste this in then fill out the image location.

Add this code to your header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/image-preload.js"></script>
```

and add this code to the .js file

```
function preloader() {
    if (document.images) {
        var img1 = new Image();
        var img2 = new Image();
        var img3 = new Image();
        var img4 = new Image();
        var img5 = new Image();
        var img6 = new Image();
        var img7 = new Image();
        var img8 = new Image();
        var img9 = new Image();
        var img10 = new Image();
        var img11 = new Image();
        var img12 = new Image();
        var img13 = new Image();
                var img14 = new Image();
                var img15 = new Image();


        img1.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img2.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img3.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img4.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img5.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img6.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img7.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img8.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img9.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img10.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img11.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img12.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img13.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img14.src = "../images/#####.jpg";
        img15.src = "../images/#####.jpg";

    }
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(preloader);
```

Comment: ohh so I preload the images which are to be shown on different pages after the home page has loaded?? Wont they be loaded again when a user visits the other pages?